# Scaling an input in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I want to attenuate an incoming signal (16 bit signed number between -1 and 1) by a certain amount (let's say 0.8), i.e.,

```
incoming = incoming * 0.8
```

Where *incoming* is a signal:

```
signal incoming : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
```

But I'm having trouble getting this to work. Inside a process block:

```
variable temp : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
variable scale_factor : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := x"6666";

begin

incoming_raw <= data_in;
temp := incoming_raw * scale_factor;
incoming <= temp(31 downto 16);

end process;
```

ModelSim doesn't like this and gives me:

```
# ** Error: /home/blah/blah.vhd(254): No feasible entries for infix operator "*".
# ** Error: /home/blah/blah.vhd(254): Bad right hand side (infix expression) in variable assignment.
```

Why can't the * operator do this when both operands are 16 bit std_logic_vectors?

Comment: Aha! My mistake, the * operator needed the operands to be cast to signed. It should have been:

    temp := std_logic_vector(signed(incoming) * signed(scale_factor));

Comment: Had to post in comments because I'm not allowed to answer my own question yet.

Comment: Or it should allow to do the same with unsigned. TBH I don't use variables. I like unsigned type more, since it is easy to cast it to any type later.

Comment: You can have `unsigned` variables just fine

Comment: Why not make `temp` `signed` also, then you don't have to cast it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this quite elegantly with the new `fixed_pkg`:

```
pr_scale : process is    
    constant b : s_fixed(0 downto -15) := to_sfixed(0.8, 0, -15);
    variable x, y : s_fixed(0 downto -15);
begin
    x        := to_sfixed(data_in, x);
    y        := resize( b * x, y);
    incoming <= to_slv(y);
end process;
```

As a side note I want to comment on the common misuse of types in VHDL: `std_logic_vector` is an array `std_logic`, which is a set of variables, signals or constants frequently used to model digital signals. `std_logic_vector` has no numerical interpretation by default, and therefore has no associated `*` operator. To do math on `std_logic_vector` you need to convert it to the correct type in one of the numerical libraries provided by the IEEE: `ieee.fixed_pkg`and `ieee.numeric_std`; only you know which one. Since both `std_logic_vector` and`(un)signed` are defined as arrays of `std_logic` they are closely-related types and can be converted with a simple cast. But due to the strong typing nature they are still different types and cannot me mixed.

As a closing remark I want to mention that there seem to be a widespread misunderstanding that you need to convert everything to `std_logic_(vector)`. Most synthesis tools will handle `numeric_std` types, integers and booleans just fine, so there is no need to discard this valuable tool of abstraction because software twenty years ago didn't support it. To quote Abraham Lincoln:

> The dogmas of the quiet past are inadequate to the stormy present.